# Cassandra - Update Set type column

Tags: collections, cassandra, datastax

We have a table in cassandra with below structure:

```
cities_in_state(state TEXT, zip TEXT, cities SET<TEXT>, PRIMARY KEY ((zip, 
state)))
```

I need to upsert the value of cities for the state with the java driver,
Have this code:

```
BoundStatement bound = session().prepare("UPDATE cities_in_state SET cities 
= cities + ? WHERE zip = ? and state = ?").bind();
bound.setSet(1, cities);
bound.setString(2, "ZIP1");
bound.setString(3, "state1");
```

which is giving error like "HashSet can not be cast to String"
And i should always need to add more cities to the existing cities.
So how would i append the set column in cassandra with bound parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Following piece of code works just fine:

```
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare("UPDATE test.st SET cities = cities + ? WHERE zip = ? and state = ?");
BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind(Collections.singleton("t2"), "2", "1");
session.execute(bound);
```

Your problem is that you're starting counting with 1, while the Java driver uses 0-based indexes.  Following piece of code works just find if I decrease every index by 1:

```
BoundStatement bound2 = prepared.bind();
bound2.setSet(0, Collections.singleton("t3"));
bound2.setString(1, "2");
bound2.setString(2, "1");
session.execute(bound2);
```

Comment: My Bad, I was missing the point that the Bound param index starts from Zero. :)